# How do you use internal static variables in Java?

Tags: java, variables, syntax, static

Is there a way to use internal *static* variables in Java? e.g take this C code:

```
void increment(){
    static int i = 0;
    i++;
    printf("%i",i);
}
```

How would I do this in Java?

Comment: For what purpose you need `static` within method?

Comment: @Azodious I need the variable to only be accessible to that method. Actually I'm porting some undo/redo code I wrote in C++ to Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java doesn't have any direct equivalent - all state which you want to be persisted across method calls has to be stored in fields rather than local variables. So you can have this:

```
private int counter = 0;

public void increment() {
    counter++;
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

... but of course the other methods in the same class have access to `counter` as well.

Answer (score 0):

for the same purpose you will have to re-write the code as per the java standard. declare the variable outside the method. It need not be static if you just want to access inside the method.

```
int i = 0;
void increment(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```